# Laravel converting right join to left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, laravel

I have been trying to convert a right join query to left join query in order to use it inside laravel query builder. Here is my Sql statement and it result wich works flawlessly

```
select `weekday`.`name`, `open_time`, `close_time` 
from `schedule` 
join `restaurants_has_schedule` on `schedule`.`id` = `restaurants_has_schedule`.`schedule_id` 
and `restaurants_has_schedule`.`restaurants_id` = 1
right join `weekday` on `weekday`.`id` = `schedule`.`weekday_id` 
ORDER BY  `weekday`.`id`

|------
|name|open_time|close_time
|------
|Domingo|NULL|NULL
|Lunes|NULL|NULL
|Martes|NULL|NULL
|Miercoles|NULL|NULL
|Jueves|14:11:51|14:11:51
|Vienes|09:11:21|17:00:00
|Sábado|NULL|NULL
```

but when convert It to left join it stop working, displaying me the same data for every single `restaurants_id`. This is my left join statement.

```
select `weekday`.`name`, `open_time`, `close_time` 
from `weekday` 
left join `schedule` on `weekday`.`id` = `schedule`.`weekday_id` 
join `restaurants_has_schedule` on `schedule`.`id` = `restaurants_has_schedule`.`schedule_id` 
and `restaurants_has_schedule`.`restaurants_id` = 1
ORDER BY  `weekday`.`id`
```

What am I doing wrong? Is There another alternative? Thak you in advance

Comment: I solved with a nested join.  
 select `weekday`.`name`, `open_time`, `close_time` 
  from `weekday` 
  left join (`schedule` join `restaurants_has_schedule` on `schedule`.`id` = `restaurants_has_schedule`.`schedule_id` 
  and `restaurants_has_schedule`.`restaurants_id` = 1) on `weekday`.`id` = `schedule`.`weekday_id` 
  ORDER BY  `weekday`.`id`

Answer (score 0):

Try use Laravels Eloquent ORM, which handles relationships really cool! no need anymore to concat or write sql-queries
See here about: [Laravels Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) & [Schema Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/schema)

Or maybe about orm's in general, you should really give it a try:

Object Role Modeling 
[Object Role Modeling](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Role_Modeling)

Example from Laravel doc:
One Post may have many comments
One to many:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }

}
```

Where 'Comment' is the model.

The "reverse" to define:

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }

}
```

Where 'Post' is the model.

And then as query:

```
$comments = Post::find(1)->comments; //by Primary Key
```

Or

```
$comments = Post::where('somefield', '=', 'somevalue')->comments->get();
```

....Really cool, for many to many see the docs@[Laravels Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)